# Какие могут быть причины того, что не отправляется вебхук на обновление заказа покупателя

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Не приходит вебхук после обновления конкретного типа сущности на конкретный адрес. Может ли быть такое, что стоит блокировка по адресу, на который отправляется запрос? Какие могут быть причины?

Comment: Уточните, какое действие происходит с заказом покупателя, после которого ожидается вебхук. Работоспособность вебхуков можно проверить по инструкции https://moysklad.github.io/workbook/api/remap/1.1/ru/webhooks.html

Comment: Изменение заказа покупателя. Проверял, вебхук отправляется на тестер.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно проблема в ssl сертификате домена, на который идет запрос.
Проверьте, точно ли установлен хук о котором идет речь.

Comment: Хук точно установлен. Уже решил проблему через отправку на другой сервер